# How to add an item to Android Studio's Navigation Drawer template and set Listener for it?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation-drawer, sample

I cant find where is `navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener` used in that sample.
I want to link that item to a fragment like what's done on the template!
Is there any other way to set `setNavigationItemSelectedListener` without overriding this method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

inside onCreate. And to answer your question I don't think so.

```
YourActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {...}
```

Inside onCreate

```
//handle drawer logic

    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Then the navigation listener

```
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        use item.getItemId to handle the clicks
drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Check for and close the drawer in OnBackPressed as well. I'm assuming you know how to load your fragment.

The default template at least on Android Studio 4.0.1 uses Navigation Component, which is meant to replace the implementation you meant in your question and the one I showed. So If you want to use navigation component refer to [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate)

Comment: There is no such method in MainActivity at template! check it.

Comment: The current template on Android Studio 4 uses Navigation Components, which are meant to replace the previous implementation which I showed above. I updated my answer with a link. If you want to use the previous implementation you can follow my answer otherwise follow link read more and where you get stuck please ask.